# Ignore Warnings From Log File

Tags: freemarker

I log files there are too many warnings are coming. We need to set the log level for free-marker templates either ignore or error. I have done some changes in below file.

conf/log4j-dev.xml

```
<logger name="freemarker.servlet" additivity="false">
    <!-- freemarker servket errors will be logged by HstFreemarkerServlet -->
    <level value="error" />
    <appender-ref ref="warnings" />
  </logger>
```

But still I can view warnings/info on log files.

```
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] FTL stack trace ("~" means nesting-related):
[WARNING] [talledLocalContainer] 12:02:37 WARN  [HstFreemarkerS
[INFO] [talledLocalContainer] ==>
```

How can i only pass ERROR on error logs in hippo.

Thanks

Comment: That particular message is not coming from `freemarker.servlet` (and, do you mean `freemarker.ext.servlet`?), but from `freemarker.core`... anyway, I guess the log category you want is simply `freemarker`. (Or better, get rid of the root cause...)

Comment: As of the cause of the WARN-s, maybe showing the full message (stack trace) helps. Also, if you log the log category as well, finding out what to filter becomes easier.

Comment: It seems not to be freemarker, see https://codehaus-cargo.github.io/cargo/Debugging.html